# Is there a way to capture or save Nunit Console test Log to a folder

Tags: c#, selenium, nunit, specflow

I have written my automation tests using c#, selenium with SpecFlow. To run them I am using Nunit. When test cases are run through Nunit whatever warning, print statements or each step in feature file details(Execution, time) etc that we see in Tests Console, Is there a way we can save them to a file and to a folder?
I want to integrate my automation tests with nightly builds and this log will save the time to see any errors or warnings and in detail list of executions. Please Help?

I am talking about the below console.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The NUnit console has the ability to output to file:
nunit-console nunit.tests.dll /out:TestResult.txt

If you look [here](https://docs.nunit.org/2.5/consoleCommandLine.html) there is more information.